# How does aggregation task benefit from inverted index in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation, inverted-index

I understand that the search task can benefit from inverted index in Elasticsearch.

But I do not understand how aggregation task benefit from inverted index. For example, if we have below docs

```
id, name,   gender, age, weight
1,  Tom,    m,      29,  100
2,  James,  m,      28,  120
3,  Lucy,   f,      27,  80
4,  Kevin,  m,      28,  150
5,  Jessica,f,      22,  100
....
```

If I want to get the average weight for age = 28, Using inverted index the elasticsearch the steps should be like

```
1. get the doc list of age = 28 which may looks like [id=2, id=4 ...]
2. Read each doc to get the weight
3. Add the weight and divide by the number of records
```

This does not seem efficient especially for the step 2. Because doc location on disk are not contiguous so the Elasticsearch can not load the data in one read, it need to read a lot of times.

So why does Elasticsearch can have such a good performance on aggregation? Does it using some other data structure besides inverted index for aggregation? Does my understanding wrong for aggregation steps?

Comment: After re-reading the doc, it seems that aggregation/sort are not benefiting from inverted index. Elasticsearch use another data structure called doc-value to improve aggregation and sort operation. But still if some one can illustrate how the doc value work would be better

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to understand that the inverted index and [other relevant Lucene files](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene70/package-summary.html#package.description) are not accessed on disk but [mapped into memory](http://jprante.github.io/lessons/2012/07/26/Mmap-with-Lucene.html) (not on the heap!) by Lucene.

So without going into too many details that's basically how ES achieves great performance for both search and aggregations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Val, But I re-read the doc and it seems Agg and sort are benefit from another data structure called doc-value. Can you help to illustrate how doc value help agg and sort?

Comment: There are very good resources that explain this much better than I would: [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/support-in-the-wild-my-biggest-elasticsearch-problem-at-scale) + but also [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/disk-based-field-data-a-k-a-doc-values) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_deep_dive_on_doc_values.html)